# [Error: Could not get albums: need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-file-system

I am trying to move a file from folder to folder in react native expo with expo_file_system and I get this error:

```
  [Error: Failed to get albums: You need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.]
```

app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-media-library",
        {
          "photosPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your photos.",
          "savePhotosPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to save photos.",
          "isAccessMediaLocationEnabled": true
        }
      ]
    ],
    ...
    "android": {
      "permissions": ["WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"],
      ...
```

what should I do?
how can get permission in expo?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this config in app.config

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-media-library",
        {
          "photosPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your photos.",
          "savePhotosPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to save photos.",
          "isAccessMediaLocationEnabled": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

refer to the below docs

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/media-library/

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/permissions/

Comment: have that but not work